# Клиент не может прочитать входящий поток

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет, клиент-сервер

Вылетает исключение EOFException в потоке-слушателе при попытке прочитать входящий поток от сервера (в строке `String entry=ois.readUTF();` )

Сервер:

```
package server2;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server2 {

    static ArrayList <SimpleServer> servers = new ArrayList <SimpleServer>();
    Socket client;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server2().go();
    }

    public void go () {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3333);
            System.out.println("connection accepted");
            System.out.println("DataInputStream and DataOutputStream created");
            while (!server.isClosed()) { 
                System.out.println("Server reading from channel");                
                client = server.accept();
                SimpleServer s = new SimpleServer(client);
                servers.add(s);
                s.start();                
                System.out.println("Connection accepted."); 
            }             
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private class SimpleServer extends Thread {
    private Socket client;
    private String name;
    private boolean fl;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private DataInputStream in;

    public SimpleServer (Socket client) {
        this.client=client;
    }

    private void writeToAll (ArrayList <SimpleServer> serversList, String smth) throws IOException {
        for (SimpleServer sr : serversList)  {
            sr.out.writeUTF(smth);
            sr.out.flush();
        }
    }

        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            try {
                out = new DataOutputStream (client.getOutputStream());
                in = new DataInputStream (client.getInputStream()); 

                while (true) {

                    //спрашиваем имя клиента 1 раз
                    while (fl==false) {
                       out.writeUTF("write your name");
                       name=in.readUTF();
                       writeToAll(servers, name+" came to chat"); 
                       out.writeUTF("Welcome to chat "+name+"\n");
                       System.out.println(name+" came to chat");
                       fl=true;
                    }   

                    String entry=in.readUTF();
                    writeToAll(servers, name+": "+entry);
                    System.out.println(name+": "+entry);

                    if (entry.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                    System.out.println("client write EXIT - client disconnectred");              
                    System.out.println("closing connection and channel");
                    System.out.println("closing connection and channel done"); 
                    break;
                }        
            }
            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            client.close();  
            this.interrupt();            
            }
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            finally {
                try {
                in.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Клиент:

```
package client;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Client extends JFrame {
    String name;
    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader br;
    DataOutputStream oos;
    DataInputStream ois; 
    String in;
    String outMessage;
    JFrame mainFrame;
    JPanel pan;
    JTextArea area;    
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    JTextField message;
    JButton button;

public Client () {
    mainFrame = new JFrame ("Client v1.0");
    pan = new JPanel();
    area = new JTextArea();    
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane (area, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    message = new JTextField(10);
    button = new JButton ("Send");
}

public static void main (String [] args) {    
    new Client().clientwork(); 
}    

    public void clientwork () {
        try {
        socket = new Socket ("localhost", 3333);
        oos = new DataOutputStream (socket.getOutputStream());
        ois = new DataInputStream (socket.getInputStream());       

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( ()-> {
        this.makeFrame();
        this.setTextArea("You connect to socket \n");
        this.setTextArea("Your's DataInputStream and DataOutputStream are initialized \n");       
        });

        //Запуск потока-слушателя
        new Thread (new ClientReader()).start();        
        }       
        catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}                        
        }

    public synchronized void setTextArea (String text) {
        area.append(text);
    }

    public void makeFrame () {       

        mainFrame.setSize(300, 400);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.add(pan);

        Border br = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);
        Border br1 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(br, "chat window", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.ABOVE_TOP );

        area.setEditable(false);
        area.setLineWrap(true);
        area.setMaximumSize(scrollPane.getMaximumSize());
        area.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        area.setLineWrap(true);
        area.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        message.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(280, 30));
        message.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        scrollPane.setSize(new Dimension (250,200));
        scrollPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());
        scrollPane.setBorder(br1);

        pan.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pan, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        pan.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        pan.add(message);

        pan.add(scrollPane);        
        pan.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (200, 40)));
        pan.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
        pan.add(message);
        button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        pan.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
        pan.add(button);
        pan.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {                      
                    outMessage=message.getText();  
                    if (outMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {                    
                        setTextArea("client killed connection \n");                       
                        setTextArea("Closing connection and channels DONE \n");
                        oos.flush();
                        oos.close();
                        ois.close();
                        mainFrame.dispose();
                        socket.close();
                }                     
                    oos.writeUTF(outMessage);
                    oos.flush();
                    message.setText("");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    try {
                        oos.flush();
                        oos.close();
                        ois.close();
                        mainFrame.dispose();
                    }
                    catch (IOException exx) {exx.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }
        }
        );  
    }    

    public class ClientReader implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            try {
               while (true) {
                   String entry=ois.readUTF();
                   setTextArea(entry+"\n"); 
               }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); System.err.println("Exception is here!");
            }
            finally {
                try {ois.close();} 
                catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сорян, разобрался.
Сервак посылает сразу 2 потока:

```
writeToAllUnlessThis(servers, name+" came to chat");
out.writeUTF("Welcome to chat "+name+"\n");
```

Клиент не успевает обработать оба, помогла небольшая выдержка по времени

```
writeToAllUnlessThis(servers, name+" came to chat");
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
out.writeUTF("Welcome to chat "+name+"\n");
```